# MySQL query help on joins and counting most occurance

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, client_table and order_table

Entries in the client_table are unique with id as primary key
In the order_table, the order_id is the primary key and also a client_id field. The client_id is the primary key of the client_table.
There can be multiple entries in the order_table that contain the same client_id. So it is a one-to-many relationship.

I'm trying to come up with a query that produce the most occurring client_id in the order_table

I have tried the following queries.

```
SELECT a.id FROM `client_table` as a  inner join order_table as b GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY count(b.client_id)
```

So I'm looking for a result of client_id which have the most orders. I suppose I only need the order_table and don't need the client_table at all right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.client_id, count(*) AS Clients
FROM order_table AS b 
GROUP BY b.client_id 
ORDER BY Clients DESC
```

No need for a join if you only want the clients id, like you said. Also, if you want to join, like in your example query, you need to specify on which column with a `ON` clause.

```
... inner join order_table as b on a.id=b.client_id ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
SELECT a.id FROM `client_table` as a  left join order_table as b ON a.id = b.client_id GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY count(b.client_id) desc
```

Use DESC at ORDER BY to get most occurances. Right now you only get the lowest occurances, and try changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You got no on clause on your join.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need the client table at all:

```
select
    client_id,
    count(order_id) order_count
from
    order_table
group by
    client_id
order by
    count(order_id) DESC
```

Comment: It orders from least to most.

Comment: Essentially it's the same as @cularis' answer, but he beat me to the punch :-)

Comment: @cularis - Ah yes, true, my bad. I've edited the order by clause.